# How do i get other component value in react?

Tags: reactjs, web-component, getvalue

I want to get in other component value.

but I not found soultion And try post {register} but it's not working...

I tried to useRef(), but it was difficult to apply because I was writing the react-form-hook package. There was a description of useRef() on the react-form-hook page, but it didn't help me.

Help me please!

[ parent component ]

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import PostcodeDaum from "../../component/Forms/DaumApi/PostcodeDaum"

const RegisterCenter = ({address}) => {
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

//

    return (
        <form className="singup-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div>
                <label>Center Address</label>     
                <PostcodeDaum ref={register}/>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

[ child component ]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DaumPostcode from "react-daum-postcode";

const PostcodeDaum = ({register}) => {
    const [isAddress, setIsAddress] = useState('');
    const [isPostOpen,setIsPostOpen] = useState(false);

    const postCodeStyle = {
//
      };

    const handleComplete = (data) => {
        let fullAddress = data.address;
        //
        setIsAddress(fullAddress);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type='text' name='address' ref={register}  readOnly = {true} defaultValue={isAddress} />
            <button type="button" onClick={()=> setIsPostOpen(true)}>검색</button>
            {isPostOpen? <DaumPostcode style={postCodeStyle} onComplete={handleComplete}/> : null}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostcodeDaum;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Modify the parent component like this:

```
return (
        <form className="singup-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div>
                <label>Center Address</label>     
                <PostcodeDaum register={register}/>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
```